# Leaflet.js, marker does not render

Tags: leaflet

Back to very basics. My leaflet map renders, I can even add a scale but I don't see the marker `L.marker([45, 1]).addTo(map);`. I suppose I don't need to add a default icon. Any clue?
The (very short) code follows exactly the Quick Start Guide: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-currying-n130o?file=/src/index.js)

The 'good' version:

```js
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";
import L from "leaflet";
const map = L.map("map").setView([45, 1], 4);

L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
  attribution:
    '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);

L.control.scale().addTo(map);
L.marker([45, 1], {icon:
  new L.Icon({iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png'})
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<div id="map" style="height:100vh"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default marker Icon is not found over the leaflet package.

Use:

```
L.marker([45, 1], {icon:
   new L.Icon({iconUrl: 'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/images/marker-icon.png'})
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: So indeed it was a pb with default icon. Thks.

Comment: To be more precise, the leaflet package on npm _does_ ship with the default icon images (that is why unpkg CDN has it as well). But online code editing services like codesandbox and StackBlitz do not support yet static assets. You can try adding a Layers Control: its icon will be missing as well.